# replace a word that start with “A” ,contains one or more "B" and end with C

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write a regex to replace

```
AAA XXX BBB XXX CCC
```

with

```
AAACCC
```

XXX can be any characters and must have one or more BBB between AAA and BBB,how to do?

Example：

```
before： AAA hello world BBB hello CCC
after： AAACCC

before： AAA hello world hello CCC
after： AAA hello world hello CCC

before： AAA hello BBB world BBB hello CCC
after： AAACCC
```

Comment: give some sample input/output, it doesn't make any sense as you've described it.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Would ^A.*B*.*C$ work?

Comment: It never fails.  What are the delimiters.  What if the word doesn't end in a C like `ABBC.` which ends in a period?

Answer (score 4):

**In c#:**

```
string text = Regex.Replace( inputString, @"AAA.+BBB.+CCC", "AAACCC" );
```

**input:**

```
AAA hello world BBB hello CCC 
AAA hello world hello CCC
AAA hello BBB world BBB hello CCC
```

**output:**

```
AAACCC 
AAA hello world hello CCC
AAACCC
```

Comment: Sorry,I forget a special input:              AAA hello world BBB hello CCC AAA hello world BBB hello CCC, and output should be   AAACCC AAACCC

Answer (score 4):

The pattern to search:

```
AAA.+?BBB.+?CCC
```

Replacement string:

```
AAACCCC
```

The trick is in `.+?` which is a non-greedy closure so that it will stop at the next match, not the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use lookahead:

```
string text = Regex.Replace( input, @"AAA(?=.*BBB).+?CCC" );
```

**Input string:**

```
AAA hello world BBB hello CCC 
AAA hello world hello CCC
AAA hello BBB world BBB hello CCC
AAA hello BBB world BBB hello CCC AAA hello BBB world BBB hello CCC
AAABBBCCC
```

**output:**

```
AAACCC 
AAA hello world hello CCC
AAACCC
AAACCC AAACCC
AAACCC
```